# clickoutside of live selector

Tags: jquery, live

I want to use the live method to hide an element if the user clicks anywhere on the page outside of that element.  It is exactly like what [clickoutside plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/) does, but with ajax loaded elements.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
$("yourelementselector").live("click", function(){
    // your code
    return false; // prevents bubbling of event
});

$("body").click(function(){
   var yourElement = $("yourelementselector");
   if (yourElement.is(:visible))
   {
       yourElement.hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$("#myElement").live('click', function(){
   return false;
});
$("body").live('click', function(){
   $("#myElement").hide();
});
```

How it works:  If you click on the element, the click event doesn't bubble up, causing a click on the `<body>` element.  If you click outside the element though, it bubbles up, eventually getting to `<body>` which hides your element.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example a modified version of the clickoutside event that works with live: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/#highlighter_680190